# java class not found D3 csv to json

Tags: java, csv, d3.js

I am trying to convert a .csv file into a json format used for creating Tree visualizations in D3. I found this link but I am unable to get the conversion file as explained in the githib link here.

[Github link used for conversion](https://github.com/albertchang/CSV-to-flare.json-D3-parser)

The name of my .csv file is "graph.csv". I ran the following commands in the src directory.

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar D3Taxonomy.java
java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar: D3Taxonomy graph.csv ","
```

I get the following error "Error: Could not find or load main class D3Taxonomy"

All the files, "D3Taxonomy.java", "graph.csv" and "json-simple-1.1.1" are in the same src folder.

Comment: We aren't going to read that Github link, understand what it means and then explain it to you: that's your job. This place is for specific code related issues.

Comment: @progyammer The github link specifies the same instructions as I have mentioned above in order to run the file. I wanted to know if there is something wrong with the way I am running the class files. I am new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same two commands and I'm getting the output.

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar D3Taxonomy.java
```

After running this in src directory, `D3Taxonomy.class` file should be generated in the same directory.
I ran the following to get the output and it worked as expected:

```
java -cp json-simple-1.1.1.jar: D3Taxonomy taxonomy.en-US.csv ">"
```

`taxonomy.en-US.csv` was in the src directory.